# Averaging, Max, and Min of Multiple Simulations

Tags: r, matrix, max, average, simulation

Trying to simulate football games in R. I want to simulate let's say 100 times and then calculate mean, max, min of the following rows for each team. Sim_number is my simulation number and will vary 1-100. Is there an easy way to do this?

|  | Team_1 | Team_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sim_number | 1.00000 | 1.00000 |
| Score | 24.00000 | 7.00000 |
| Pass Yards | 164.53623 | 233.0000 |

Comment: What technology are you asking about? Are you looking for an SQL query? A spreadsheet? Code in some language?

Comment: @Nadav Zingerman asks an important question -- I'm going to assume because your post is tagged 'R' that that's what you're looking for. The package `rsimsum` is designed for summary statistics of simulation data. If you want something more specific, you'll have to provide a reproducible example in your post, starting with the data. Not sure what that means? This post answers that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example